# Reading value from buffer efficiently

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a `std::vector<char>` buffer in memory with a number at a specific offset, e.g.

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 33 2E 31 34 99 99 99 .........3.14™™™
```

I know the end and start offset to read the double/float value, but right now I'm copying the relevant part with `std::copy()` into a `std::string` and then calling `std::stod`. My question is: how can I make this faster?

There must be a way to avoid the copy.. for instance: can I point a stream to a specific offset in another buffer? Or something similar perhaps

Comment: Ps. I don't think this is subjective. I can rephrase the entire question as to "Can I avoid the copy?" if necessary

Comment: Is the number delimited by some character that cannot be part of the number?

Comment: @user2079303 Nope, it should be in the form `0.23424`, I'm not even expecting a `-` or `+`. The dot is the decimal separator

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the buffer could have string 0.23456 and you might want to extract 0.23 only since the rest is not part of the number?

Comment: If the limit is before `456` yes, I might have to do that

Comment: Ok, is the buffer zero terminated?

Comment: Well, it's a file mapping. It surely should have an EOF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers were delimited, then using `strtod`  directly on the buffer like Let_Me_Be suggests is efficient. However, since the numbers are *not* delimited, you cannot use `strtod` directly.

If the buffer is zero (or eof) terminated, then you can simply modify it, by adding the terminator after the number, and then restore the original character, like bolov suggested. Since the end offset is part of the number, there's always at least the terminator after it, so `offset_end` won't overflow. The following code assumes that `offset_end` is one past the last character. If it's the last character, then simply use `+ 1`.

```
auto original = data[offset_end];
data[offset_end] = '\0';
auto result = strtod(&data[offset_start], nullptr);
data[offset_end] = original;
```

Even, if the buffer is not terminated, you can still do that, but only if the number is not at the very end. If it is, or if you don't know where the buffer ends, or the buffer is `const`, then your current solution is as efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the offset then simply:

```
vector<char> data;
// ... snip ...
char *endp = null;
double result = strtod(&data[offset],&endp);
```

Note: This assumes that the number is followed by non-numeric characters (or end of string).

Comment: If it's okay to modify the `data` buffer, then you could write a null byte to the (known) end position before calling `strtod`.

Comment: you could save the original end value and restore it after strtod

Comment: Doesn't deal well with the end position but could work